# Desconecta frequentemente Laravel App

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, auth

Criei um **CMS** sobre a plataforma do Laravel 5.2, criado todo o sistema de usuário (login, register, reset pass, logout), porém o usuário desconecta frequentemente, já desabilitei o **Middleware VerifyCsrfToken** porém nada acontece.

Isso acontece do nada, ao atualizar alguma página, já alterei o **lefttime** para **1200000** e de nada adiantou, ele é redirecionado para a Rota de login.

O que vocês acham que pode ser?

Comment: Verifica session.gc_maxlifetime na config do php.ini este é o tempo de vida da sessão, tenta aumentar este tempo e ver se resolve.

Comment: Cara, ainda não resolveu o problema, alterei para **100000000**.